# Xml validation using xsd not caught

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've been trying to validate my xml file using XmlSchemaSet but for some reason the error is not getting caught when I read the xml. I'm almost certain that the problem is not in my xml or xsd because when I have the xml open in visual studio it actually tells me that my attribute contains an invalid value.

Xml:

```
<Test xmlns:testns="http://schemas.testnamespace.com/" xmlns="http://schemas.testnamespace.com/"
  testns:foo="-903" />
```

xsd (example taken from Microsoft's documentation on xsd:union)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.testnamespace.com/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.testnamespace.com/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified" >

    <xs:element name="Test" >
        <xs:complexType>

            <xs:attribute name="foo">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:union memberTypes="fontbynumber fontbystringname" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>

        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="fontbynumber">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="72"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="fontbystringname">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="small"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="medium"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="large"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Validation code:

```
XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();

//Passing null instead of the namespace doesn't change anything
sc.Add("http://schemas.testnamespace.com/", "Bar.xsd");
sc.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
sc.Compile();

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
//I've tried all combinations of ValidationFlags and it doesn't change anything
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
settings.Schemas = sc;

using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
{
    while(reader.Read()) ;
}
```

I feel like the problem might be in union because whenever I used union or list it never catches any error but as soon as I just use restriction without union or list it catches the error..

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Testing on .net 2.0 & 4.61 and it works as expected.

You got the right file in the 'path' variable?

[image]

Comment: Yes the path is correct and the xsd also works because if I add an invalid attribute the error gets caught or if I only have a restriction and no union the error also gets caught. I'm using .net 3.5, I'm really lost now, we have the same code how come my error doesn't get caught? Hmm I'm gonna try using .net 4.61 and see if that changes anything.

Comment: The only difference was that you were using a console application while I was using the Unity Engine environment so I created a test console application project, put the code there and it worked..? This is the weirdest thing ever because every other errors gets caught except that one and I don't see why the environment would matter, anyways I'll try investigating this further, thanks for the help.

Comment: Odd, what version of System.Xml.dll are you referencing?

Comment: Runtime Version: v4.0.30319 and Version: 4.0.0.0, I know it's very weird, I wouldn't be so perplexed if no errors at all were caught but the fact that the only errors not caught are when union or list is used is just so weird.